# ¿Como leer mi base de datos en Firebase Admin?

Tags: java, base-de-datos, firebase, jsp, real-time

**Hola, mundo!**

Mi problema es que no me carga o inicia el método de lectura de datos de firebase, por ahora creo que puede ser por la ruta que especifico, pero ya he probado con el método que me propone  [su documentacion](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write?hl=es-419)  y también con el método que se utiliza en android (ya que las clases son prácticamente las mismas) y nada nunca me carga el apartado de `onDataChange`. Actualmente estoy trabajando con una **web jsp** y trato de conectarla con firebase para recibir y actualizar datos.

**método de parecido al que se usa en Android:**

```
public float[] PromedioTotal(){
    float[] a=new float[6];
     System.out.println("El metodo si carga ");
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("proyecto1");
     System.out.println("si entra en datos");
    // Attach a listener to read the data at our posts reference
    ref.child("PromediosGasWeb").child("total").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Promedio post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Promedio.class);

        a[0]=post.getDia1();
        a[1]=post.getDia2();
        a[2]=post.getDia3();
        a[3]=post.getDia4();
        a[4]=post.getDia5();
        a[5]=post.getDia6();
        a[6]=post.getDia7();
       // System.out.println(post);
        System.out.println("si entra en datos2");

      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
      }
    });
    return a;

}
```

**Metodo guiado por la documentacion oficial de firebase admin**

```
    public float[] PromedioTotal(){
    float[] a=new float[6];
     System.out.println("El metodo si carga ");
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("proyecto1/PromediosWeb/total");
     System.out.println("si entra en datos");
    // Attach a listener to read the data at our posts reference
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Promedio post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Promedio.class);

        a[0]=post.getDia1();
        a[1]=post.getDia2();
        a[2]=post.getDia3();
        a[3]=post.getDia4();
        a[4]=post.getDia5();
        a[5]=post.getDia6();
        a[6]=post.getDia7();
       // System.out.println(post);
        System.out.println("si entra en datos2");

      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
      }
    });
    return a;

}
```

Nunca lanza en mensaje `System.out.println("si entra en datos2");`, no se, si es que mi método sale antes de esperar respuesta de Firebase.

**Mi Estructura de bases de datos**

```
proyecto1 (base de datos):
PromediosWeb (hijo padre):
total (hijo padre2):
dia1=0 (hijo o item)
dia2=1 (hijo o item)
dia3=2 (hijo o item)
dia4=3 (hijo o item)
dia5=4 (hijo o item)
dia6=5 (hijo o item)
dia7=6 (hijo o item)
```

La base de datos le pertenece a una app movil Android y mi web deberá administrarla.

**Metodo Promedio**

```
public static class Promedio{
        private float dia1,dia2,dia3,dia4,dia5,dia6,dia7;

        public Promedio(float dia1,float dia2,float dia3,float dia4,float dia5,float dia6,float dia7){
          this.dia1=dia1;
          this.dia2=dia2;
          this.dia3=dia3;
          this.dia4=dia4;
          this.dia5=dia5;
          this.dia6=dia6;
          this.dia7=dia7;

        }

        public float getDia1()
        {
            return dia1;
        }
        public float getDia2()
        {
            return dia2;
        }
        public float getDia3()
        {
            return dia3;
        }
        public float getDia4()
        {
            return dia4;
        }
        public float getDia5()
        {
            return dia5;
        }
        public float getDia6()
        {
            return dia6;
        }
        public float getDia7()
        {
            return dia7;
        }
    }
```

**Gracias y espero su pronto apoyo.**

Answer (score 0):

La documentación que estas siguiendo no es la correcta, ya que no estas usando android.

Por Frank Van Puffelen

> El acceso a la base de datos Firebase desde una JVM normal (no
>   Android) se considera una plataforma de servidor por la documentación
>   de Firebase. Puede encontrar todo sobre esto en la [documentación de
>   Firebase para los SDK de su servidor](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start).

Con esa documentación deberias poder leer tu base de datos.

Comment: Amigo gracias, pero yo también probé los métodos de admin y utilice el ejemplo que coloque.